# How to overcome "System fan (90B)" error during startup on HP 240 G8

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, fan

About a half year ago we bought dozen laptops HP 240 G8. Recently 3 of them, sometimes, started to show "System fan (90B)" error during startup. If i choose boot, the fan spins with full speed, The air temperature that comes out of ventilation hole is cool.

When i searched through Google, it showed answers for old laptops where the fan just stuck, and it is needed to disassemble and clean it. But it is definitely not in this case, since it is new laptop and the fan spins without any extraneous sounds.

I also updated BIOS to last version F.21 without result. The Hardware monitor app shows CPUs temperature is quite low - around 50 Celsius.

What would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: Considering that you have bought them fairly recently (under 1 year) why not go back to HP to get them to get it checked / fixed?

Comment: Are they in dusty locations, where heat sink could be covered in dust? Also, are the problematic PC's vertical or horizontal? There have been cases where liquid metal used for heat transfer has trickled out of a vertically mounted device: https://www.extremetech.com/gaming/342062-reports-suggest-the-ps5-might-leak-liquid-metal-overheat-if-left-vertical . If so, HP is responsible for any issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that new AMI BIOS version F22 solved that issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your're right, i have to return it to the shop. Actually they was used in office conditions where is not dusty.
Interesting, when i reinstalled windows in order to wipe the laptop before returning, this error stopped showing. And the fan is spinning normally for several days.
Do not know if it will appear again. Hopefully not.

Thank you for your answers!